# Function return type for template class inside template class

Tags: c++, templates

I am using c++ templates and created a template class inside a template class.

the situation is like this:

```
template <typename T>
class C {
    public:
    class N {
        T v;
    };

    template <typename D>
    N *fun(D d);
};

template <typename T>
template <typename D>
N *C<T>::fun(D d) {
}

int main() {
    C<int> obj;
    obj.fun('c');
}
```

Now compiler is giving error as:

> main.cpp:14:1: error: ‘N’ does not name a type

If I use the function prototype outside class as 
`C<T>::N *C<T>::fun(D d)`, compiler gives error:

> main.cpp:14:1: error: need ‘typename’ before ‘C::N’ because ‘C’ is a dependent scope

If I define definition inside the class then it works fine. But I don't want to make it inline, how should I do it?

Comment: related : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords/613132#613132

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As the compile error suggests, use `typename`

```
template <typename T>
template <typename D>
typename C<T>::N *C<T>::fun(D d) {
}
```

Comment: better don't refer to comments. They can go at any time. If your intention was to give credits, thanks, but credits should go to the one who writes the answer, while I should feel bad for giving away parts of the answer in a comment ;)

Answer (score 2):

As alternative, you might use trailing return type:

```
template <typename T>
template <typename D>
auto C<T>::fun(D d) -> N*
{
    return nullptr;
}
```